# Prune unused images in OpenShift Origin 1.1.6

Tags: image, docker, openshift-origin

I try to delete unused images on my cluster. Some images which aren't used are on my nodes. Some of those images are also still in my registry. (They were a previous version of an image). So now I want to delete the unused old images, on my nodes and in my openshift registry.

First I tried the docker-way:

```
docker images -q |xargs docker rmi
```

But then I got something as:

```
REPOSITORY                                     TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE

172.30.xx.xx:5000/proj/image   <none>              8b447558582d        18 hours ago        567.1 MB
<none>                                         <none>              a8cf2d4c61d0        2 days ago          439.4 MB
<none>                                         <none>              b89dba477f35        6 days ago          699.8 MB
<none>                                         <none>              07e013fb74a4        8 days ago          225.8 MB
```

`oc get images` showed some layers too.
I tried to prune images with the command `oadm prune images` (without the confirm) but than I got:

```
I0421 07:34:10.872320   42525 imagepruner.go:430] Unable to find image "sha256:7a28aee39fd0e7097f566d6292ff1x7302aa9c049e00f2e5aa48bdb66346a717" in the graph
I0421 07:34:10.872436   42525 imagepruner.go:430] Unable to find image "sha256:c21e91864b4cd05fa0b8feab124x3b95f313456dba32ce3d6ad9f6a7a31a9074" in the graph
I0421 07:34:10.872460   42525 imagepruner.go:430] Unable to find image "sha256:09654488a537e791a8d17403c067x8b49a26b7d72239ed7a3fcd313d34747b19" in the graph
I0421 07:34:10.872501   42525 imagepruner.go:430] Unable to find image "sha256:0404ab93a5a48fbf068c88c2fx6a473db171be88ae16a493dcf8dc43d946a177" in the graph
I0421 07:34:10.872511   42525 imagepruner.go:430] Unable to find image "sha256:4ac3571f302ee97xdb35cc05008d2f037890d120b44958f85c4392e4ddffb21a" in the graph
I0421 07:34:10.872984   42525 imagepruner.go:430] Unable to find image "sha256:7a28aee39fx0e7097f566d6292ff157302aa9c049e00f2e5aa48bdb66346a717" in the graph
```

I see the image layer sha256... also when I perform the `oc get images` command so it's really there.

It's deleting nothing (also with --confirm). I also don't know if it normally will delete unused images on my nodes or also delete the images in my registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenShift automatically removes unused images on individual machines when they are no longer used, although how aggressively or quickly they are removed depends on how much disk is needed on the node. You can tweak the settings on each machine with https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/garbage_collection.html#image-garbage-collection

The prune command will purge unreferenced images, but is fairly conservative. Only older images will be removed - see https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/pruning_resources.html for a deeper discussion of the flags.